# Web pages no longer linked after hosting upload, why?

Tags: web-hosting

I have uploaded my website, with the local URL, the pages were linked fine, I could move from one page to the other by clicking the appropriate button. Upon upload to my hosting, the web pages are no longer linked. Once I visit the domain, I can't navigate the web pages. What's the solution?
e.g here's what a working file path looks like on my PC, href="desktop/folderx/aboutus.html" here is the file path I have for public_html which does not work, href="/home/public_html/aboutus.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your webserver, everything is referenced to **public_html**.  Therefore if you are using absolute paths it would be `/aboutus.html`.

You will have to find a way to remap the paths.  Use some way to figure out if you are in **debug** mode and use a different path for the pages.  I use an environment variable to set **debug** mode.  And I check it in my php code to alter the path that I am using for **internal pages**.